# Jquery $(this) not working at class selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

thanks for your time

i have the following jquery ui dialog

```
$(function() {
        $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
            title: $(this).attr('name')+'WHYYY',
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode"
        });
```

the html is simple like this:

```
    <div class="dialog" style="" id="helper" name="helper">
    <textarea id="helper_e" name="helper_e">
    some text
    </textarea>
    </div>
<!--and so on with multiple dialog classes with different id's and name's-->
```

intented to take the name as the title.

it does not work, outputing the following in title:

```
UNDEFINEDWHYYY
```

Why? thanks for a hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` does NOT refer to `div.dialog` as you might expect. It refers to `window.document` instead. You should rewrite it like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.dialog').each(function() {
        var props = {
            title: $(this).attr('name')+'WHYYY',
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode"
        };

        $(this).dialog(props);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` doesn't have the correct value in the context you are trying to use it.

Assuming you can't add a title attr, you could loop over the items in the .dialog selector and add the title attr programatically.

```
$( ".dialog" )
    .each(function () {
         $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('name')+'WHYYY');
    }) 
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });
```

Comment: hi, i got i now working with the open event but i am curious why jquery does not recognize the this on each of the individual class fields.

Comment: @Email It has nothing to do with jQuery. `this` is a Javascript construct, you can read about it for example [on QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).